# UIAlertView if app terminates due to memory?

Tags: memory, uialertview

Is there a way to show a UIAlertView if my app terminates due to lack of memory? I believe that it is better than just terminating the app without any message - the user should realize that this is a transient memory problem and not a bug in the app.

I have an app on my iphone that shows such an alert and then terminates (I hope that it's not the way this app handles all memory warnings :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible ! you need to first track uncaught exceptions & then you can display a alert,i m not sure you understand if i explain the concept, so try with this  link

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html

run the project in the link at bottom of page, here u will the solution,

The Gd thing is if any error caused in any part of app it will trace & alert & you , simply you need make allocations in your app appdelegate class.

we use these concepts to warn user's if any app dies with low memory & will have option to ask user to sent report to us , thereby helpful to track what caused it & all!

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the information and the link. I downloaded your project, but unfortunately it doesn't behave as expected. The exception handler  never gets called. As soon as the error is signaled, the app terminates with a regular error message on the log as if NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler was never called. Any ideas?